# Combinatorial Proof of $(n)_{k} = \sum_{j=k}^{n} k(j-1)_{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove via a combinatoric question that $$(n)_{k} = \sum_{j=k}^{n} k(j-1)_{k-1}$$

I don't see how the two are equal mathematically in the first place. Take n=5, k=4:$$(5)_{4} = 5*4*3*2$$. The right hand of the equation is then $$\sum_{j=k=4}^{5} k(k-1)_{k-1}$$, equaling $$4(3)_{3} + 5(4)_{4} = 4*3*2*1 + 5*4*3*2*1$$. Where'd I go wrong here?

Comment: In your last display, $5(4)_4$ should be $4(4)_3$.

Comment: Stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: You rewrote the sum incorrectly. When $k=4$ and $n=5$, the sum is $\sum_{j=4}^5 4(j-1)_3$.

Comment: **Please avoid double dollar symbols on titles**.

Answer (score 1):

You allowed $k$ to vary in your sum with $j$. It should have been $4(3)_3+4(4)_3.$

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the notation $n^{\underline k}$ for the falling factorial.

Your computational mistake is that the general term in the summation is $k(j-1)^{\underline{k-1}}$, not $j(j-1)^{\underline{k-1}}$, so for $n=5$ and $k=4$ the righthand side is

$$4\cdot 3^{\underline 3}+4\cdot 4^{\underline 3}=4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1+4\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2=120=5^{\underline 4}\;.$$

For a combinatorial argument, the natural place to start is with the fact that $n^{\underline k}$ is the number of sequences of $k$ integers chosen without replacement from the set $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. On the righthand side we’re apparently breaking these up into subcategories, one for each $j$ from $k$ through $n$, in such a way that category $j$ has $k(j-1)^{\underline{k-1}}$ elements.

Now $kj^{\underline{k-1}}$ is clearly the number of ways to choose a sequence of $k-1$ integers from $[j-1]$ and then to choose one integer from some set of $k$ integers. Concentrate on the first part and worry about $k$ later: $j$ ranges from $k$ through $n$, and we’re choosing a sequence of $k-1$ integers from those less than $j$. Here’s where you need a small flash of ingenuity: $j$ is covering the range of possible values for the largest of the chosen $k$ numbers, and $(j-1)^{\underline{k-1}}$ is the number of ways to form the **rest** of the chosen sequence. Once those $k-1$ numbers have been chosen, there are $k$ ways to insert the largest, $j$, into the sequence, so there are $k(j-1)^{\underline{k-1}}$ ways to choose a sequence with maximum element $j$.